# Are the definitions of a continuous multivariate random variable from the Lebesgue decomposition and the continuity of the cdf equivalent?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

For a univariate random variable $X$, it's probability measure decomposes into $\nu=\nu_c+\nu_s+\nu_d$ by the  Lebesgue decomposition, where $\nu_c$ is absolutely continuous, $\nu_s$ is singular continuous and $\nu_d$ is discrete.

Then we can define a random variable as continuous if its probability measure is $\nu_c+\nu_s$, and this is equivalent to each of the following: (i) $\nu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
(ii) the cdf of $X$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.

But now for a multivariate random variable $X$, how does the definition of a continuous random variable work. I believe it is one where the probability measure is $\nu_c+\nu_s$. And this is equivalent to (i) $\nu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. But this is not equivalent to (ii) the cdf of $X$ is a continuous function on  $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Is this correct? For example the bivariate random variable $(Y,0)$, where $Y\sim N(0,1)$ is continuous singular, and hence continuous, but does not have a continuous cdf.

I have seen some books define a continuous multivariate random variable as having a continuous cdf on $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. How does this relate to other notions of continuous random variables? Am I correct in saying that definition would not be equivalent to any of the above-mentioned notions of a multivariate continuous distribution, and also not equivalent to the existence of a joint probability density?

Comment: I think you are correct. Existence of a density is stronger than continuity of the cdf, even in 1d.